# If $x>10^2$ then is the following statement true? $1-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3}{x^2}>0.9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> If $x>10^2$ then is the following statement true?
>   $$1\color{red}-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3}{x^2}>0.9$$

I already figure out that $x>10^2$ implied: $$-2/x>-2\cdot10^{-2}$$
$$3/x^2<3\cdot10^{-4}$$

But because of the different inequalities signs, I couldn't mix them to find out the result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s easier if you get $x$ into the numerator. Multiply through by $x^2$ to get $x^2-2x+3>0.9x^2$, bring everything over to the lefthand side to get $0.1x^2-2x+3>0$, and multiply by $10$ to get $x^2-20x+30>0$. Rewrite this as $x(x-20)+30>0$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Nope :( Tried different kinds of approaches.

Comment: @Adobe: You’re probably trying to be too fancy. If $x\ge 20$, $x(x-20)\ge 0$, so ... ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it even with my numerous attempts ...

Comment: @Adobe: There really isn’t much of anything still to do. If $x>10^2$, then certainly $x\ge 20$, so $x(x-20)\ge 0$, and $x(x-20)+30\ge 30$. Thus, $x^2-20x+30>0$ whenever $x>10^2$, and since the inequality $x^2-20x+30>0$ is equivalent to the original one, the original one also holds whenever $x>10^2$. (In fact $10^2$ is overkill: $x\ge 20$ is more than enough.)

Comment: Sorry, sometimes my brain plays with me evil games, that was a very efficient way where I haven't paid much attention. Thanks, that was extremely helpful!

Comment: @Adobe: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Multiply by $x^2$ we find
$$0.1 x^2-2x+3>0(*)$$
and the reduced discriminant $\Delta'=1-0.3=0.7$ and  the roots $x'=10-10\sqrt{0.7}$ and $x''=10+10\sqrt{0.7}$ hence if $x>10^2>x''$ we have $(*)$

Comment: Thanks! That's also a smart easy way to derive the result.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I found a relatively simpler method to work out the result.

We have that: $$x\gt10^2$$
It follows that: $$\begin{align}\dfrac1x & \lt0,01\\\,\\\dfrac2x&\lt0,02\\\,\\-\dfrac2x&\gt-0,02\\\,\\1-\dfrac2x&\gt0,98\gt0,9\end{align}$$
$$1-\dfrac2x\gt 0,9\tag{$\star$}$$
And since $x$ is strictly positive, then: $$\dfrac{3}{x^2}\gt0\tag{$*$}$$ 
Therefore, from $\text{($\star$)}$ and $\text{($*$)}$: $$\color{red}{\boxed{\,\,\color{black}{\,\,1-\dfrac2x+\dfrac{3}{x^2}\gt0,9}\,\,}}\tag{1}$$

Comment: Could the downvoter explain his act?

Answer (score 0):

Another Approach: Notice

$$ 1 - \frac{2}{x} + \frac{3}{x^2} > 0.9 \iff x^2 - 20x + 30 > 0 \iff (x - 10)^2 > 70 > 64 = 8^2$$.

Now, consider the increasing function $f(x) = x^2$. By hypothesis, we are given $x > 100$ which implies $x - 10 > 90 > 8 $. So, $x-10 > 8 \implies (x-10)^2 > 8^2 $ since $x^2$ is increasing. But this is what we wanted to show.